# ASP.NET webhooks : receive webhook into aplication

Tags: asp.net, webhooks, asp.net-webhooks

I have an application which has a feature where user can post message into a channel like for internal communication.
I am thinking to implement webhooks where we can get third parties data into channel.it may an alert from server or anything similar.
is this possible using ASP.NET webhook custom packages?
if yes, any idea from where I can start or for this moment it only support /receive data into the supported parties?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, that's absolutely possible. A big part of ASP.NET WebHooks is that you can enable your own WebHook support (under the Custom namespace). There are several samples showing how to do this and you can also see this blog [1]

Hope this helps!

Henrik

[1] https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/03/05/announcing-asp-net-webhooks-release-candidate-1/

Comment: Thanks a lot @henrik, can we create custom our own receivers/senders using asp.net webForms .net 4.5 as the asp.net web-hooks code targets on asp.net mvc 5 and web api2?

Comment: Is it possible to `WebHookReceiver` for `.Net Core`? If yes, any sample reference would be just awesome!

Comment: .Net Core: https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks  .Net Framework https://github.com/aspnet/aspnetwebhooks